# Structural Equation Modeling without Latent Variables

Tags: references, structural-equation-modeling

I am learning and have used Structural Equation Models with latent variables, with measurement models and path analysis.

It seems however, that I should be able to use them even without latent variables-- maybe if I just conduct the path analysis without looking into measurement models, which would not be required in the absence of latent constructs.

I would also be grateful for any reading material on this, both theoretical and applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do structural equation models without latent variables.

Regression, t-tests (paired and unpaired) can all be considered to be SEMs without latent variables. In addition, things like mediation analysis, or cross-lagged regression analysis, can also be done as SEMs, without (or with) latent variables.

(Well, in a sense that's not true. Almost all models have an error term, and that can be considered a latent variable.)

The first chapter of Loehlin's book 'Latent Variable Models: An Introduction to Factor, Path, and Structural Equation Analysis' talks about SEMs without latent variables.